# How to get rid of an additional vert that shows up during the manual bevel operation

Tags: vertices, edges

[image]

[image]

As the screenshots suggest, I can not make a bevel without this little vert showing up, although I chose 3 edges only. How can I turn off this little annoyance?

Comment: I don't think you can, you need to rework the topology afterwards

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you mean with "this little vert". The one building the bottom of the triangle at the end of the bevel? Well, that's how the bevel works. How do you think those two edges created by the bevel go over into a single edge? What do you want it to look like?